# How to call a block inside a view page?

Tags: views, 8

I am working with Drupal 8. I have a view page and added a twig for that.

I want to call a block inside my view page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some possible ways to do it:

## 1. using no extra modules

Click ADD next to header or footer area and look for `GLOBAL: Rendered entity - Block`.  The configuration asks for `view mode` and `block id`

[image]

## 2.  using  Views block area module

You can use [Views block area](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_area) module that will allow you to insert a block as a field or in header or footer area.

## 3.  using preprocess / twig

if you want to add the block using your twig template in your `THEMENAME.theme` file using a `preprocess` function

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_XXX (&$variables) {
    $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('id_block');
    $variables['myBlock'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getViewBuilder('block')
        ->view($block);
}
```

and then inside your twig file use this

```
{{ myBlock }}
```

To find appropriate preprocess function look in your twig file comments.

For example if you want to use `views-view--unformatted.html.twig` you can see in the comments

```
* @see template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()
```

which means include in your `.theme` file `THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()` function

Answer (score 2):

You can use module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) this module you can render view,block ...
You can see document [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak)

Render views

```
{{ drupal_view('who_s_new', 'block_1') }}
```

Render blocks

```
{{ drupal_block(plugin_id) }}
```